# Optimizing Custom React Hooks - data fetching

Tags: react-hooks

I'm very new with React Hooks and I understand that I can use React Hooks inside a function component.  I'm used to use Redux instead of Hooks.  What I want to achieve is code reuse, where like Redux, you can have actions stored in 1 files and export them, and use them in many class based components.  For example, in many components, I need to have a list of available Departments, which I can get easily by initiating with action then read the results in the reducers/store.

Back to reality in Hooks world, I can use useState, useEffect, etc inside every functional component, but that would be very bad practice in terms of code reuse.  So I try to create a custom hooks, where I just call the hooks, and I got the result and the component can refresh.

So with this simple create-react-app, I have a custom hooks saved in a file hooks.js like this :

```
export const useGW = (pcode) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
    console.log("useGW()");
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchGW() {
            console.log("fetchGW()");
            var options = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json', "XSP": pcode },
                url: '=====EDITED======'
            };
            let res = await axios(options)
            setResponse(res.data);
        }
        fetchGW();
    },[])
    return response
}
```

and from the App.js I just import it and call it :

```
function App() {
  const response = useGW('dev');
  console.log('oGW : ', response);
```

the problem is, it prints out :

- useGW()
- oGW : {empty object}
- useGW()
- oGW : {empty object}
- fetchGW()
- oGW : {with correct response}
- useGW()
- oGW : {with correct response}

I don't understand why it is so not efficient that it re-renders 4x ?
How do I make it efficient ?
I've tried to play with [] of useEffect, but the re-render amount is the same.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: _"I'm used to use Redux instead of Hooks"_ - hooks are not an alternative of redux and extra renders are most probably because of [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: Hi Yousaf, thank you so much for your reply. if I turn off the StrictMode,  it really seems solve the problem.  It prints out : - useGW() - oGW : {empty object} - fetchGW() - useGW() - oGW : {with correct response }.  You save my day !  Thanks a lot